# For every positive integer $n$, the free group of rank 2 has a subgroup of index $n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm trying to prove that for every positive integer $n$, the free group of rank 2 has a subgroup of index $n$.

My idea was to think of transitive group actions on $n$ elements and find an action of $\mathcal{F}(2)$  on $S= \{1, 2, ..., n\}$ such that $|Orb(s)|=[\mathcal{F}(2) :Stab(s)]=n$. The best I could come up with so far is something like this:

$f:\mathcal{F}(2)\times S\rightarrow S$
$\qquad x_{j}^{d} \ast i \mapsto (i+jd) \; mod \; n $

Am I on the right track? If so, how could I pull everything together to form the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with presentation of groups, then the only thing you need is to find a presentation  $<X|R>$ for a group of order $n$ where - in your question - $|X| = 2$. The simplest example is $G = <x,y| x^n = 1, x=y >$. In this example, the subgroup of index $n$ in the free group generated by $x,y$ is the normal closure of the set $\{x^n, xy^{-1}\}$.

Comment: In other words: if your free group $F$ is generated by $x$ and $y$, then let $f$ be the unique group homomorphism from $F$ to $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ satisfying $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=1+n\Bbb Z$. Then the kernel of $f$ will have index $n$ in $F$.

Comment: @Amin thanks for your answer. I am new to presentations and don't fully understand... what is "$R$" in your answer, and is "normal closure" the subgroup generated by the set of conjugates of $\{ x^{n},xy^{-1} \}$ in the free group?

Comment: Also @GregMartin, I understand your comment as an answer on its own, but would you please elaborate a bit on the parallel between your wording and that of Amin ? I can't completely make the connection...

Comment: @e.g $R$ can be any subset of $F= <X>$. The normal closure of $R$ is $F$ (denoting by $<\bar{R}>$) is the intersection of all normal subgroups of $F$ that contain $R$. So it is the smallest normal subgroup of $F$ containing $R$. The group $<X|R>$ by definition is just $F / <\bar{R}>$. This is how we construct a presentation. So a reverse argument shows that if we have a presentation $<X|R>$ for a group $G$ of order $n$, then we have a free group $<X>$ and a subgroup (indeed a normal one) $N = <\bar{R}>$ of index $n$.